# PHP called Javascript function not accepting parameters

Tags: javascript, php, parameters

Javascript:

```
function clickedLink(l){
     alert(l);
}
```

PHP:

If I don't pass in a parameter, like this. It returns undefined, which is correct.

```
echo '<tr class='.$class.' onclick="clickedLink();">;
```

If I try to pass a parameter in nothing happens.

```
  echo '<tr class='.$class.' onclick="clickedLink("test");">';
  echo '<tr class='.$class.' onclick="clickedLink(\"test\");">';
  echo '<tr class='.$class.' onclick="clickedLink('.$test.');">';
```

Any idea on why it's not working? It might be me not understanding how to access Javascript parameters inside the function.

Comment: Check the rendered source to see if the quotes make sense.  I would have thought option 2 would work maybe try backslash single quote around test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding \' like this

clickedLink(\'.$test.\')

Comment: Where should I add that?

Comment: Add the backslash before the single quotes in the clickedLink function. See if this works.

Comment: That does work when it's not a variable but when it is it comments it out.       
   echo '<tr class='.$class.' onclick="clickedLink(\'test\');">';

Comment: Try a single quote, not a double quote.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot.              onClick="clickedLink(\''.$test.'\');"           I had to double up on the single quotes.